# Java library to convert InDesign file to image (jpg, png, etc.)

Tags: java, adobe-indesign

I have a Java webapp that works with InDesign files, I need my application to be able to show a preview of the file and also to send it to the printer. Is there some library that can take the InDesign file and convert it to an image file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you've had any luck with this, but we use [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) for this kind of thing. It's not a java library but we access it in java via the command line, and it works really well.

Comment: As far as I know, Image Magick doesn't sopport InDesign, does it?